# probability of throwing three adjacent numbers

Tags: probability

When throwing one dice 3 times in a row, what is the probability of getting adjacent numbers in right order, for example 2,3,4 or 4,3,2?

Comment: In how many ways can we choose a *set* of $3$ adjacent numbers? For each choice, $2$ orderings are allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, the posible combinations are:
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\{1,2,3\}&&
\{3,2,1\}\\
\{2,3,4\}&&
\{4,3,2\}\\
\{3,4,5\}&&
\{5,4,3\}\\
\{4,5,6\}&&
\{6,5,4\}\\
\end{array}$$

So, there's $8$ useful combinations, out of $6^3=216$ total posible combinations. Then
$$P=\frac{8}{216}$$

---

We can generalize the result, obviously: say we want a set of $k$ adjacent numbers out of $n$ total sides.

Then, we have a total of $n^k$ total possible combinations ($k$ throws of an $n$-sided dice), and 
$$2(n-k+1)$$ 
useful combinations: you only can form $n-k+1$ ordered subsets of adjacent numbers (the $k$ first adjacent numbers, the $k$ second, and so on); and we are allowing adjacent numbers forwardly and backwardly ($2$ times).

Finally, the probability is
$$P_n(k)=\frac{2(n-k+1)}{n^k}$$

Answer (score 1):

Record the results of the throws as an ordered triple $(a,b,c)$, where each of $a,b,c$ is a positive integer between $1$ and $6$.

There are $6^3$ such triples, all *equally likely*.

Now we count the number of *favourables*, that is, ordered triples in which the numbers obtained are consecutive, in ascending or descending order.

We can choose the order in $2$ ways, ascending or descending. For ascending, the smallest number can be any of $1,2,3,4$, and then the rest are determined. The same is true of descending. So the number of favourables is $(2)(4)$.

It follows that the required probability is $\dfrac{(2)(4)}{6^3}$.

Answer (score 1):

There are exactly $8$ of these series of adjacent numbers. Any series has probability $6^{-3}$ to occur so...